# Why isn't the grid_forget method working?

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to make an tkinter atm gui, in the gui I made it so you can create new accounts with a set balance. I also wanted to make it so you can delete the last previous account you created but ran into an error. I stored all created accounts in a list and to delete them I tried to use the grid_forget method to delete the account in the -1 index but the program says it doesn't have an attribute called grid_forget, please help and thank you.

code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

class BankAccount(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, frame_title):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(frame_title)
        self.geometry("350x370")
        self.acc_list = []
        #main window buttons
        self.addAcc_button = tk.Button(self, text="Add Account", width=50, height=3, command=self.addAcc_window)
        self.addAcc_button.grid()
        self.removeAcc_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear accounts", width=50, height=3, command=self.removeAcc)
        self.removeAcc_button.grid()
        self.deposit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Deposit", width=50, height=3)
        self.deposit_button.grid()
        self.withdrawal_button = tk.Button(self, text="Withdraw", width=50, height=3)
        self.withdrawal_button.grid()

        #main window label
        self.accounts_label = tk.Label(self, text="Accounts: ", justify="center")
        self.accounts_label.grid(pady=10)

    #create second window when add acc* button is pressed + done button function/command
    def addAcc_window(self):
        self.AAW = tk.Toplevel(self)

        self.accName_label = tk.Label(self.AAW, text="Enter Account Name:")
        self.accName_label.grid()
        self.accName_entry = tk.Entry(self.AAW)
        self.accName_entry.grid()
        self.AAW_done_button = tk.Button(self.AAW, text="Done", command=self.AAW_Done_button)
        self.AAW_done_button.grid(pady=20)
    def AAW_Done_button(self):
        if len(self.accName_entry.get()) == 0:
            mb.showerror("Blank entry", "Field cannot be blank")
        else:
            self.add_accLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Account " + self.accName_entry.get() + ": Balance($0)")
            self.add_accLabel.grid()
            self.acc_list.append(self.accName_entry.get())

            self.AAW.destroy()

    #create third window when remove acc* button is pressed
    def removeAcc(self):
        self.acc_list[-1].grid_forget()


root = BankAccount("ATM")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `self.acc_list` contains the name of the accounts, so they are all strings which does not have `grid_forget()` function.

For your case, you need to add two things into `self.acc_list` for each account:

- the account name
- the label showing account name and balance

```py
def AAW_Done_button(self):
    ...
    self.acc_list.append([self.accName_entry.get(), self.add_accLabel])
    ...
```

Then you can delete the last account inside `removeAcc()` as below:

```py
def removeAcc(self):
    if self.acc_list:
        name, label = self.acc_list.pop()
        label.grid_forget() # or better call label.destroy()
```